# How to extract types of strings?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, lambda

I am collecting data of financial instruments. For every financial instrument there is a unique currency added. I now want to extract how many unique types of currency I have.

For example, given the following string array:

```cs
string[] cur = {"HKD", "HKD", "HKD", "EUR", "EUR", "USD"};
```

My desired output would be:

```
HKD EUR USD
```

I haven't tried anything because I am not sure how to approach this. Can anyone give me guidance?

Answer (score 4):

There is a [`Distinct()` method in LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0) which gives unique items.

```cs
string[] items = {"HKD", "HKD", "HKD", "EUR", "EUR", "USD"};
IEnumerable<string> uniqueItems = items.Distinct<string>();  
Console.WriteLine("Unique array elements is " + string.Join(",", uniqueItems));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want distinct elements in your collection why not use use a HashSet. Just suggesting.

Comment: There's nothing in the question to suggest that this is the _only_ purpose for this collection.

Comment: Do not post comments as answers.